# Invalid OpenAPI JSON file - Expected type object but found type string for security definition

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, swagger, openapi

I'm getting a validation error for the following openApi.json file, which I'm trying to configure in order to use JWT authentication to my Endpoints service on Google Cloud. I'm following this guide - https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#configure_auth. The error can be easily reproduced by pasting and validating my sample using the [Swagger online parser](https://apidevtools.org/swagger-parser/online/). The error message is:

```
Swagger schema validation failed. 
  Expected type object but found type string at #/paths//my/api/get/responses/200/description/securityDefinitions/mySecurityDefinition/x-google-jwks_uri/x-google-issuer/type/flow/authorizationUrl/security/0
JSON_OBJECT_VALIDATION_FAILED
```

I'd like to understand why I get the message `Expected type object but found type string`. The error message looks like it's maybe complaining about the security definition, but I'm not seeing why.

**openapi.json**

```
{
 "swagger": "2.0",
 "info": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "title": "my-app-hostname.appspot.com"
 },
 "host": "my-app-hostname.appspot.com",
 "basePath": "/api",
 "schemes": [
  "https"
 ],
 "consumes": [
  "application/json"
 ],
 "produces": [
  "application/json"
 ],
 "security" : [
   "mySecurityDefinition"
 ],
 "securityDefinitions": {
    "mySecurityDefinition": {
      "authorizationUrl": "",
      "flow": "implicit",
      "type": "oauth2",
      "x-google-issuer": "myServiceAccountEmailAddress",
      "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/myServiceAccountEmailAddress"
    }
 },
 "paths": {
  "/my/api": {
   "get": {
    "responses": {
     "200": {
      "description": "A successful response"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? If I change the 1st object in the `security` array to this, then it doesn't validate, but the parser gives no error message:

```
 "security" : [
  {
    "mySecurityDefinition": [ ]
  }
 ],
```

Comment: `"mySecurityDefinition": [ ]` is the correct version. After making this change, your openapi.json file is reported as valid (green) by https://apidevtools.org/swagger-parser/online/. What do you mean by "it doesn't validate, but the parser gives no error message"?

Comment: @Helen - ah, OK, thanks. So green is being shown to indicate some degree of validity, but I'm not sure what. What I mean is that when I click 'Validate it', the Swagger validator pane still shakes to suggest 'no, that didn't work', and shows some of the text in red. So I'm guessing the green means it's syntactically valid but the shaking means something's still not correct? And I'm not sure what is still wrong.